# Options to connect remotely on local Database without Static IPV4 Address

Tags: sql-server, ip, database-connection, ipv4

I have a SQL Server database located on my pc that I need to connect to remotely. I enabled the remote access and adjusted my firewall settings and used my public IP address. But when I turn my pc off and then on, my public IP will change so I have to get my new IP every time. I read the a solution is to get a static IPv4, but they are really expensive, so is there any other solution? Like a way I can get automatically the public IP of my pc from another pc?

Comment: This is off-topic here. Google for "dynamic DNS service" and if you need more help try on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Public IP you get is for just identify your machine on global network and it changes dynamically from time to time.
Static IP provides your machine to identify on global network.
You can use your machine on LAN without static IP.
And for internet you need machine with static IP or use global server as your machine.